# "func azure functionapp publish" returns error code 400

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have followed every step in [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/wiki/Create-your-first-Python-function) to create a Python function app in Azure, but when I run `func azure functionapp publish myApp`, it returns:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

This didn't give me much info. What does this mean? How can I debug this error? Anyone else experiencing this?

**EDIT:**

Found out I can see some console with `CLI_DEBUG=1` flag. This gave me this:

> GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01
>   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01
>   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01
>   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   Azure.Functions.Cli.Helpers.AzureHelper.ArmHttpAsync[T](HttpMethod
>   method, Uri uri, String accessToken, Object payload)    at
>   Azure.Functions.Cli.Helpers.AzureHelper.GetFunctionApp(String name,
>   String accessToken)    at
>   Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.RunAsync()
>   at Azure.Functions.Cli.ConsoleApp.RunAsync[T](String[] args,
>   IContainer container)

**EDIT 2:**

I tried another method of getting this up in Azure. When I run az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g myRG -n myApp --src myFiles.zip, I get:

> Failed to retrieve Scm Uri
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py",
>   line 197, in invoke cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py",
>   line 369, in execute six.reraise(*sys.exc_info()) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py",
>   line 693, in reraise raise value File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py",
>   line 343, in execute result = cmd(params) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py",
>   line 182, in call return self.handler(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/init.py",
>   line 436, in default_command_handler result = op(**command_args) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py",
>   line 170, in enable_zip_deploy scm_url = _get_scm_url(cmd,
>   resource_group_name, name, slot) File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.44/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py",
>   line 1153, in _get_scm_url raise ValueError('Failed to retrieve Scm
>   Uri') ValueError: Failed to retrieve Scm Uri

So I can't reach kudu / scm, neither here or with Portal  ...

Comment: Can you try to stop the Function before publishing it (e.g. through the Azure Portal)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried stopping it now, did not matter. Same error: _Response status code does not indicate success: 400. _ I actually tried pushing an app I know does not exist, and the exact same thing happens... Could this indicate an error with the "connection" with Azure?

Comment: open a CLI issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues

Comment: It is possible your subscription does not allow creating python functions. Please open an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. Did not find any answer online, but ultimately resolved by preceding with **az login** command to login form Azure CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login). Hope this helps.